# Perl: Given an arbitrary string, how do you extract the first N bits?

Tags: perl

Given a string $old_str, I am trying to extract the first N bits (not bytes) into $new_str. I have been reading the pack documentation and perlpacktut, but am hopelessly confused. This is where I currently stand:

```
my $old_str = "9876543210";                                                     
# Extract the first 5 bits
my $new_str = pack("B5", unpack("B*", $old_str));
printf "%#b | %#b\n", $new_str, $old_str;
```

This produces:

```
0b1000 | 0b1001001100101100000001011011101010
```

But I want this:

```
0b10010 | 0b1001001100101100000001011011101010
```

Comment: If you know how to get the bits into a string, then do that, and get the first five of them using a substring. Which part do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

You want the vec built-in: [vec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/vec.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html):

```
my $bit_string = unpack( 'b*', $old_str );
```

It will create a string of 80 '1's (char 0x31s) and '0's (char 0x30s). On Windows, you will probably need to add [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html).

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what you are trying to do here. The `unpack("B*", $old_str)` creates a bit string containing the following bits (spaces added for readability):

```
00111001 00111000 00110111 00110110 00110101 00110100 00110011 00110010 00110001 00110000
```

…in other words, a bit string corresponding to ASCII numbers for your characters:

```
$ perl -E "printf('%#b ', ord) for split(//, '9876543210')"
0b111001 0b111000 0b110111 0b110110 0b110101 0b110100 0b110011 0b110010 0b110001 0b110000
```

Then you do `pack('B5', '00111001…')` which seems to be a bit complex. It looks like `pack` returns a byte consisting of the five rightmost bits in the first 8-tuple (`11001`). That gives 56 or the `8` string (since the ASCII for `8` is 56):

```
$ perl -E "say ord pack('B5', '00111001…')"
56
$ perl -E "say pack('B5', '00111001…')"
8
```

And when you `printf` the string, you get the binary numeric representation of the number 8:

```
$ perl -E "say printf '%#b', '8'"
0b10001
```

(This is crazy.)